# React - How to get property of an object inside an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, redux

I have an array of **SidebarItems** which accepts objects, inside the object there are 2 properties, **name** and **route**, I want to use name value as route value, but I am getting an error called **Unexpected use of 'name'**, here is my actual code

```
const SidebarItems = [
    {
        name: "Calendar",
        route: `/${name}`,
    },
];

export default SidebarItems;
```

Comment: you should call like SidebarItems[0].name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't really reference the `name` like that. What you can do is to generate the array for example in the following way:

```
const SidebarItems = ['Calendar', 'Messages', 'Notifications'].map((itemName) => ({
   name: itemName,
   route: `/${itemName}`
}));
```

Answer (score 1):

You need something like

```
const SidebarItems = ({ name, route }) => ([
    {
        name: "Calendar",
        route: `/${name}`,
    },
]);

export default SidebarItems;
```